# Render react component multiple times

Tags: reactjs

I have some posts on page, [ imagine this ] and i need my  to be added at the bottom of each of those posts, Just like Facebook,

But how can I do this ?

```
React.renderComponent(<CommentForm />,document.getElementById('someId'));
```

is what react tutorial says..

Do I have to iterate through all the posts and append the  to that ?

```
$.each($('.post .commentArea', function(key, elem) {
  React.renderComponent(<CommentForm />, elem); 
})
```

If I have it like this ? How do I mount the CommentForm when there is a new post on the page ?

Comment: I hope I've understood you rigth. You try to append your `CommentForm` component to each post?
Do you add your posts as react components, too? If so, you can easy nest your `CommentForm`:
`return <Post>bla <CommentForm /></Post>;`
If not, why do you want to add react components to existing HTML?

Comment: So this is the issue, I need the current posts to be rendered using a php backend so then it will be SEO friendly, Also I need the react js functionality just for the comments made on them as the comments will not available for SEO,, Do i make sense ? Im sorry if I dont

Comment: @Johann https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/8900/ This is exactly what I need, But this does not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user3656084, this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/8907/) will work.

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>{this.props.content}</div>;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.each( $('.post .commentForm'), function(key, elem) {
        console.log(elem)
        React.render(<CommentForm content="Bla" />, elem);
    });
});
```

Comment: my man, That work perfectly, Thanks very much :) Now I need to build on top of this

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's listening to an array, which let's say in this case is a list of posts.

Once the the **lists** in store changed, the view will get event and update the UI accordingly. Something like this should do the render work.

```
renderList() {
  return _.map(this.state.lists, (list) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <div> list.title </div>
        <div> list.body </div>
      </div>
    )
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <header />
      {this.renderList()}
      <footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Sorry I dont this I explained properly, https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/8895/ If you see this post I have the post div and the commentForm class where the <CommentForm /> should be rendered

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/8900/ This is what I need exactly, This fiddle does not work :(